Adobe Acrobat print booklet - prints blank pages on each left side
I'm trying to print a pdf as a booklet. The PDF is 61 A4 pages with images and text. When I print and select Booklet, it prints with a blank page on each left side. I googled and read the page count needs to be a multiple of 4, so I added 3 extra pages (each with a word on so it's not blank), but the same problem occurrs. I've also tried adding 1, 2 and 3 extra pages separately to no avail.

This is my print dialog. All settings are default. I've set the printer to Print to PDF so I can test the result without wasting paper/toner. The problem still occurs when printing for real.
This is the result pdf showing the blank pages:

Any help is much appreciated!
Thank you.

Booklet Printing is intended for re-ordering pages into part pages (n-up) so they can be folded into a booklet.
There are many formats such as 4 pages on card to FOLD for a birthday card.
Or in this case a classroom handout.
The point to note, is even numbers are expected (normally 4's ), and the last page is moved to the first Left Hand position to form the back page when folded.

The result in this case will be 4 pages to be double sided on 2 sheets of paper.

It should not matter if the numbers are not divisible by 4 since often the answer sheet is not expected to be part of the print.

Question
Why does the source file always prints blank left half pages in booklet mode.
Answer
The source file has a hidden (cropped) left half page, that is automatically used by Acrobat Reader when booklet printing, and cannot easily be disregarded, without removal.
One way to do that is re-print the right half pages to single pages, "avoiding" Microsoft printing unless no other method.
For 61 pages then extra pages 2, 63 and 64 need to be arranged to provide a blank inside cover (2) and last double back page (63) and cover (64), say for notes or answers.
On seeing the originals it is best if blanks are simply 62, 63 (facing) and 64 as back cover. keeping all source pairs as facing pages allowing for "see opposite" or double spreads, etc.
So once remediated 64 pages will work.


I tried even numbers: 64 pages total and it still gives me blank pages on the left.

Thank you. I have added the original source files to the Google Drive. It's got the title page + each indvidual maths lesson. Due to the layout of the source files (two pages per side of sheet) I had to split each one in half. I used deftpdf. Next, I combined the title page with each divided pdf into one (which is the 61 page example I shared). What can I do to do the same process but without the bigger page issue? I wonder if a better tool would do it. Maybe it's the deftpdf splitter?

Interesting. Can you check the Google Drive? I've uploaded what could be a working version. Ready to print.pdf is the title page, halved pages and 1 blank page. I printed that to pdf as a booklet to get Printed to pdf - is this ok.pdf. This looks mostly ok to me. The cover sheet has a blank side which will be the back. Pages 2 and 3 have half blanks - is that ok? I'm not near my printer now so I can't physically print it - only to pdf. The difference is I used online2pdf.com to split the pages down the middle, then the same website to merge the title, halves and 1 blank.

Thanks. In the printed to pdf version (which should simulate actual print result), is it ok to have the blanks on sheets 2 and 3. I expected a blank on sheet 1 for the back but not the others. Duplex printing should be ok as my printer prints both sides (large commercial printer)

Thanks. How do I check if it's A4/letter and metric/imperial?

What do you do to find the page size? For example, if I use another web site to make a new pdf, how can I know the size and if it's letter or A4?
